# Window Service installed but EndPointNotFoundException was caught

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wcf-binding

I am struggling to get out from this exception. I don't know why it is thrown always.
My service( server) installed correctly from insaller and it is running in the background.
But server has exposed the end points in a way :

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/PlcInputService/" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VbgServiceBinding" contract="Eplusv.Vbg.InfoViewer.VbgService.IPlcInputService" name="PlcInputServiceEndpoint" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/CameraService/" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VbgServiceBinding" contract="Eplusv.Vbg.InfoViewer.VbgService.ICameraService" name="CameraServiceEndpoint" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/PanelService/" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VbgServiceBinding" contract="Eplusv.Vbg.InfoViewer.VbgService.IPanelService" name="PanelServiceEndpoint" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
```

But as soon as I send test data after opening the service, to the very first end point exposed by server. it throws the following exception

There was no at net.tcp://localhost:8732/PlcInputService a listening endpoint available that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. For more details, see "InnerException", if any.

while my app.config for this service is :

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
  <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true" />   
</diagnostics>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings configSource="bindings.config" />
<services configSource="services.config" />
```

bindings.config and services.config containing the same endpoints which i mentioned above.

I have no idea why it is occuring and how to get around from it.

Regards
Usman

Comment: if you type "netstat /a" in the command prompt can you see anything with port 8732 open? If not then it's not up and running.

Comment: Yes..I found. It is there with the following inforamtion.

TCP  0.0.0.0:8732            LUCAS-PC2:0                Listen

Comment: but I can't see any Ip address attached with 8732.
Only 0.0.0.0 : 8732..any idea?

Comment: Since you are not using named pipes, I guess the connecting client is calling from outside the server? Is the firewall open for outbound connection for port 8732 as well?

Comment: Yes..you are right 
it is from outside server , seperate process. I also checked Firewall. But it doesn't looks that it is blocking any connection to establish with port 8732. Can you guide how can I check? I manually entered Port 8732 for recieving all kind of traffic.

Comment: It kind of depends on how your infrastructure is set up as well and who is administrating it. Just because you open a port in the firewall doesnt have to mean it's open for communication if the network itself doesn't allow it. Are you administrating the servers yourself? Or perhaps you have to request opening the port from a network administrator first?

Comment: These all services are running in the server locally on my machine.
But the service which has to talk on 8732 port, for this, the data is coming from IO Port of the PC. This IO Port is connected with seperate PLC which is sending the data pulses to it.

Comment: the firewalls in both ends need to enable the TCP port at 8732. If you are sure this is the case, would you describe how you instanciate the service host with the contract classes? say, can you post the codes?